# Periodic posting to multiple twitter accounts using Java

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I want to periodically post set of tweets to multiple twitter accounts. To accomplish this task, I have used tweetdeck.twitter.com, had created a twitter account and added all the other accounts that I need to post on under my account.

I have created a Java application using twitter4j library that connects to my twitter account and posts on my timeline.

How can I extend the use of this application to get the other accounts and post for them using twitter4j APIs?

Comment: Do you have a database in order to store the account credentials?

Comment: Yes I have an Excel sheet of twitter accounts credentials

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's too late to answer but it may aid other users, I recently encountered this situation, and I've used below approach :-

- Store all twitter credentials(I prefer calling them handler details) and tweets in DB
- Maintain a relationship between tweet and the handler over which it need to be posted.
- Create a scheduler to pick up scheduled tweet and then pick the linked/appropriate handler and simply tweet.

Hope this help.